# Instantly show autocompletion results using Android's search dialog

Tags: android, search

I am redesigning the search interface for my Android App. I've red Google's API guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

The current version of the app uses the classic system search dialog. It lacks autocompletion which I want to provide in the new version.

My requirements in terms of auto-completion: If the query string is less than 3 characters, the app should auto-suggest search results based on the set of stored favorites which are stored locally. If the query consists of at least 3 characters, the search shall be conducted remotely via a search API.

Since historically, the App's minimum API will be level 7, I cannot use Honeycomb's SearchView (API 11+) or ActionBarSherlock SearchView (API 8+). I decided to stick with search dialog provided by the SearchManager.

I've sucessfully implemented all requirements stated above.

Though, one thing reduces the usability.

When the user starts the search, the search dialog gains focus. The desired behaviour is that instantly, all favorites are suggested. Though, this is only true on my HTC Legend running Froyo (2.2). On my Galaxy Nexus, the app most of the times does not instantly show all suggestions. I get callbacks to my SearchProvider not until the user has entered at least one character.

My question: is there a way to instantly show suggestions/get a callback to the SearchProvider across all Android versions starting API 7+?

I've tried different calls to the SearchManager (startSearch()) but with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. I am thinking of switching to SearchView which is much more flexible